# windows phone 8 button's commandparameter { binding}

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am somewhat new in windows phone 8 and getting lost in this {Binding} stuff. i want to know how does this button commandparameter binding? and what does this commandparameter binding to?

```
   <data:MoviesByCategory x:Key="movies"/>
    <data:MoreCommand x:Key="moreCommand" />
 <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="codeMovies" IsGroupingEnabled="true"
                                      ItemsSource="{StaticResource movies}"
                                      ListHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource movieListHeader}"
                                      GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource movieGroupHeader}"
                                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource movieItemTemplate}"
                                      JumpListStyle="{StaticResource MoviesJumpListStyle}"
                                      toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">

                <!-- The group footer template, for groups in the main list -->
                <phone:LongListSelector.GroupFooterTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button DataContext="{Binding}" Content="{Binding GetMore}"
                                Command="{StaticResource moreCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.GroupFooterTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `{Binding}` will bind to the current DataContext so setting `DataContext="{Binding}"` can just be removed as it do absolutely nothing. 
Since `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` is inside the GroupFooterTemplate, the dataContext will be your movie group and thus it will be what CommandParameter is binded to.

Comment: *"can just be removed as it do absolutely nothing."* Unless the command parameter required is the movie displayed on the button.

Comment: @Will whatever is done, setting DataContext="{Binding}" has strictly no effect, by default the DataContext is automatically inherited from the parent so setting it explicitly will have no effect. The important binding is CommandParameter="{Binding}".

Comment: No, the DataContext does *not* flow to the CommandParameter of a button.  So, if you need to pass the current content of the DataContext into a command via the CommandParameter, you **must** use a binding.  To say it has "strictly no effect" is completely incorrect.  Try it for yourself.

Comment: @Will I said DataContext="{Binding}" has no effect, not CommandParameter="{Binding}".  Using DataContext="{Binding}" is exactly the same thing has doing this.DataContext=this.DataContext;

Comment: Okay, I'm going to go eat some worms now.